# How to check type of new added pad?

Tags: c++, audio, video, gstreamer, glib

My pipeline scheme(dynamic link):

> videotestsrc OR audiotestsrc ! decodebin ! queue ! autovideosink OR
>   autoaudiosink

I trying to use [this advice](https://delog.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/link-dynamic-pads-of-demuxer/) to check which type of data I got (video/audio), but if I use decodebin like demuxer, then I get just **"src_0"** instead of **"audio"** or **"video"**. How I can check my pad type for linking right element for playback? May be I can use one universal element for audio playback and video playback, like playsink(but it does not work for video)?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the caps of the newly added pad and check if it contains audio or video caps (or something else).

Try with:

```
gst_pad_get_current_caps (pad);
```

or:

```
gst_pad_get_allowed_caps (pad);
```

If you are using gstreamer 0.10 (which is 3+ years obsolete an unmantained), you have:

```
gst_pad_get_caps_reffed (pad);
```

Then just check the returned caps if it is audio or video by getting the structure from the caps and checking if its name starts with video or audio.

```
/* There might be multiple structures depending on how you do it,
 * but usually checking one in this case is enough */
structure = gst_caps_get_structure (caps, 0);
name = gst_structure_get_name (structure);
if (g_str_has_prefix (name, "video/")) {
   ...
} else if (g_str_has_prefix (name, "audio/")) {
   ...
}
```